# Reading a file into a JavaFX grid by reading the first character of each line to modularly create a form?

Tags: java, file, javafx

I'm trying to create a method in JavaFX that can modularly create forms by reading a text file and constructing it based on the first letter of each line.

I've gotten to the point where I can fill out a checkbox with options but I can't get the readFile method to discriminate between lines with 'Q' or 'A'.

Without my discrimination clauses it returns all the lines of the file, but with them it reads none of them (as if they're never true) but I can't comprehend why.

```
//Method reads files into a string and then returns the result, which should be the completed string
//Currently trying a modular solution based on a mode system with 'Q' being the input for Question reading
// and 'A' being the input for Answer reading
public String readFile(String file, char mode) throws IOException {
    //in = new FileInputStream(s);
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //Buffered reader for reading file
    String i = "";
    while ((br.read()) != -1) {
        /*This doesn't work
        if (mode == 'Q' && br.readLine().charAt(0) == 'Q') {
            i += br.readLine() + "\n";
        }
        if (mode == 'A' && br.readLine().charAt(0) == 'A') {
            i += br.readLine() + "\n";
        }*/
    }
    return i;//return statement
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `br.read()` in the `while` condition, it reads a character (the first character of the line). So when you subsequently call `readLine()`, you get the remaining characters on the line (i.e. not the first character). Similarly, you call `readLine()` once in the test, and then you call it again when you concatenate the text, so you will concatenate the line *after* the line you tested, not the line you actually tested.

Note also that it is very bad practice to build a string by concatenation in a loop. On each iteration of the loop, you create a new string, and copy the existing characters from the previous string. Since the size of the strings are growing, this runs in quadratic time, and likely places extra burden on the garbage collector. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

You can do

```
public String readFile(String file, char mode) throws IOException {
    //in = new FileInputStream(s);
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //Buffered reader for reading file
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line ;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (mode == 'Q' && line.charAt(0) == 'Q') {
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        if (mode == 'A' && line.charAt(0) == 'A') {
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }
    return result.toString(); //return statement
}
```

A more "Java 8" approach for this would be:

```
public String readFile(String file, char mode) {
    if (mode != 'Q' && mode != 'A') return "" ; 

    return Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
        .filter(line -> line.charAt(0) == mode)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

To drop the first character from the returned string, in the first version replace `result.append(line)` with `result.append(line.substring(1))`. In the second version add the line

```
.map(line -> line.substring(1))
```

between the `.filter` and the `.collect`.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Would you also know how I could ignore that first character? With this solution it outputs it like "AYes" and "ANo"

Comment: Just don't append the first character. E.g. replace `result.append(line)` with `result.append(line.substring(1))`.

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful.

Comment: @BenBoudreau Added a more modern approach to the answer.